# Why Erlang / Elixir observer memory usage numbers do not add up?

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am starting out with Elixir and observing some strange behavior when connect to my remote production node using iex.

As in the screenshot below, the observer reports that total of ***92 MB*** memory is in use. However, when you sum up the memory consumption of processes, atoms, binaries, code and ets, it comes up to be: ***~69 MB***

```
Processes  19.00 MB
    Atoms   0.97 MB (969 kB)
 Binaries  13.00 MB
     Code  28.00 MB
      ETS   7.69 MB (7685 kB)
-------------------
    Total  68.66 MB
```

[image]

So, my first question is where is this extra ***23 MB*** of memory is coming from? I am pretty sure its not just a reporting issue. Because when I look at my Kubernetes pod's memory consumption, it is ***~102 MB*** which is in alignment with the numbers observer is showing.

[image]

> Only thing I can think of is that those ***23 MB*** has not been garbage collected yet. Is my assumption valid? If so, its been 6 hours since this container started. And I have been monitoring the memory consumption from very beginning. Shouldn't this be garbage collected by now?

And second question: are there any Erlang VM / Elixir configuration tweaks I can make to optimize on memory footprint?

Comment: You'd need to dive into the VM to get exact figures, but there's also stack, the VM, and probably an algorithm at work that bumps up the pages allocated to the process (most likely the figure for "total") in large increments. Is there any particular reason you need to use every byte of RAM? Usually, I don't look at these stats at all and I work quite a bit on memory-constrained devices like the RPi...

Answer (score 5):

I have also been attempting to solve issues regarding memory management in OTP applications and one tool that has been particularly useful for me is the library written by Fred Hebert called [recon](https://github.com/ferd/recon). Especially the `recon_alloc` module that provides very useful information on memory usage in the Erlang VM.

### The missing MegaBytes

The following quote is directly taken from the documentation of the `recon_alloc:memory()` function and might provide you an insight of what's going on :

> The memory reported by `allocated' should roughly match what the OS
>   reports. If this amount is different by a large margin, it may be the
>   sign that someone is allocating memory in C directly, outside of
>   Erlang's own allocator -- a big warning sign. There are currently
>   three sources of memory alloction that are not counted towards this
>   value: The cached segments in the mseg allocator, any memory allocated
>   as a super carrier, and small pieces of memory allocated during
>   startup before the memory allocators are initialized. Also note that
>   low memory usages can be the sign of fragmentation in memory, in which
>   case exploring which specific allocator is at fault is recommended.

So I think that the extra 23 MB of memory usage might be caused by some undesired allocations, or perhaps due to fragmentation.

---

### Tweaking ( with great caution /!\ )

As for your second question, there is a tool in Erlang called [erts_alloc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erts_alloc.html) that also describes manual configuration of memory allocators. It can be done by passing command-line flags to the emulator, for example :

`erl +SOMEFLAG +SOMEOTHERFLAG`

But there's a big red warning in the documentation that strongly suggests that messing with these flags can result in much worse behaviour than with the default configuration.

So my advice would be to resort to these modifications if it is really the only way to solve the problem. In that case, there is a [book](https://happi.github.io/theBeamBook/) about the Erlang Runtime System that has helped me understanding some aspects so I would also recommend giving it a read beforehand.

**NOTE :** Wild shot in the dark here and not answering your question directly, but it might be useful to double check what is going on with your binaries, as I see that there are 13 MB reported by the observer. Depending on their size (smaller or larger than 64 bytes), they are stored in process heaps or accessed by reference. I have faced case #1 with lots of small binaries piling up and ultimately crashing my system.

---

There are a few other helpful resources I found while trying to fix those problems :

- This specific snippet from a [blog post](https://blog.heroku.com/logplex-down-the-rabbit-hole) authored by Fred Hebert as well :

> `[erlang:garbage_collect(Pid) || Pid <- processes()].`

It will trigger a GC on all running processes immediately. In my case it has done wonders. You can add an option to call it asynchronously too, so you don't have to block until it's all done :

> `[erlang:garbage_collect(Pid, [{async, RequestId}]) || Pid <- processes()].`

- This [article](https://prog21.dadgum.com/16.html) about GC in Erlang
- Efficiency guidelines in the [Erlang docs](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html#how-binaries-are-implemented) for binaries, that provide useful implementation details.
- [Stuff goes Bad : Erlang in Anger](https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ferd.erlang-in-anger/text.v1.1.0.pdf), another free ebook written by ... yes it is Fred Hebert.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the detailed response!

Comment: Glad to see it wasn't too late ! You are very welcome :)